# Window Disk Partition not shown in Ubuntu installation process

Tags: installation, grub2

I had installed Windows OS on my laptop and I tried to install Ubuntu on the next drive. But during the installation process, the Ubuntu installer *does  not show or recognize my drive partitions (created through Windows)*. But on Ubuntu live session, it shows the partition and contents. I think the problem is with Windows *grub file isn't detected by Ubuntu*. Is there any possible method to handle this problem without formatting the Windows drive(partition)?

Comment: Are you using SoftRaid or FakeRaid on our system? Also, Windows does not use any "Grub files". Try using Advanced partitioning.

Comment: I had Used `EASEUS Partition Master 6.5.2 Home Edition` for partition of driver.Before this My computer get restart to apply the partition using that software,But this time it don't restart to apply it. I don't know why.On ubuntu Partition manager don't show partition

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what random damage it can cause due to its not being standard compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solve this by formatting all disk and make partition with help of bootable CD of Window 7. I think problem is created due to installation of Window 7 using pen drive. (As I had deleted all disk along with System Reserved before installing window 7 using pen derive)